# Finding car's average acceleration?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, time, acceleration, velocity

I am trying to calculate the car's average acceleration in (m/s^2) between 0 and 2.1 s. I need to express this answer using two significant figures, I have been trying the following to get it and it keeps telling me my answer is wrong, what am I doing wrong?

[image]

a = (delta v)/(delta time)
a = (60 - 0) / (2.1)
a = 28.57

Comment: Try the whole time period.

Comment: Did you check the units? It seems that you have the speed in $mi/h$ and you said that you need to calculate the average acceleration in $m/s^2$

Comment: @DelCrosB I tried doing 60*60*60 to convert it to miles/second for velocity than dividing that by 2.1 which gave me 102857.14 however it's still not taking it.

Comment: @Farcher what do you mean by the whole time period? It asks for the average acceleration from 0 to 2.1. Maybe get average for entire time than use that for 2.1 seconds?

Comment: Sorry my mistake.  You need to convert 60 miles per hour into metres per second and having done the calculation quote the answer to 2 significant figures not 2 decimal places.

Comment: @Farcher thanks the for that response finally got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is wrong is the units. You are doing

$$ \frac{(60 \mbox{ miles/hr})}{(2.1 \mbox{ sec})} = 28.57 \mbox{ mph/s } $$

What you need to do is convert the speed into $\mbox{m/s}$

$$ (60 \mbox{ miles/hr}) = ( \frac{1}{3600}60 \mbox{ miles/sec} ) = ( 1610 \frac{1}{3600} 60 \mbox{ meter/sec}) = 26.833 \mbox{ m/s} $$

Now do the acceleration as

$$ \frac{(26.833 \mbox{ meter/sec})}{(2.1 \mbox{ sec})} = ... \mbox{m/s}^2 $$